# MS build logging

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

How to enable logging in msbuild.
My build is failing, I don't know why.
Is there any property that needs to be set in the property group.

Comment: What are you using to kick it off? TFS, CC, custom script, something entirely different?

Comment: TFSbuild.proj script run by TFS

Answer (score 14):

### Within **Visual Studio**

You can view the log in the `Output` view with `Show output from:` set on `Build`.

To configure the verbosity go to `Tools > Options... > Projects and Solutions > Build and run`

### FileLogger

You could use the MSBuild `FileLogger` like that :

```
msbuild.exe /fileLogger 
 /fileloggerparameters:LogFile=[Path_to_log_file];Verbosity=[minimal/normal/detailed/diagnostic]
```

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Continous integration environment are you using if you using an Cruisecontrol.NET, there is a XMLLogger, which can do the trick for you. but if you want to enable logging in your MSBuild script then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx should do the trick for you.

Comment: NO im not using CCnET, I am using MSBuild using Visual studio instead of command line